# vscode windows: cannot open output file test.exe: Permission denied

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, permissions, g++, mingw

[image]

I tried to run the basic C++ code on vscode I get as error:

```
Error: cannot open output file test.exe: Permission denied.
```

I am able to run Python code on VS Code but facing issue with C++ code only.

Comment: Sometimes this problem is caused because you haven't quit a previous instance of  test.exe. You cannot overwrite test.exe while it is still running.

Comment: I checked the file from task manager they is no such file is running. Even tried to run different code with different file name, still getting the same error.

Comment: @VishalChauhan can you post your `tasks.json` and `launch.json` files here?

Comment: Make sure the project is in a normal path without any spaces in it. Also make sure it's not on a OneDrive share. Just try moving the project somewhere else on your disk and try to build it there.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you didn't terminate the running test.exe.
Open Task Manager , then search for test.exe ( order by name to find it easier) and terminate it.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting(Rebooting) the entire system helps for me. Still haven't find anything that causes this error, might be ending "main.exe" task in task manager details tab will help.